# AngularFire WebSocket Error: Network Error 12152, The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Note: The code is still functional, there is just the error that I can't get to go away.

I'm trying to get started with Firebase, but not even the Quickstart code seems to run error free. Core from here: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#tutorial/angular/3

I have also tried the newest version of the library, 1.2.

I get the following errors:

Chrome:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://s-usc1c-demo-1.firebaseio-demo.com/.ws?v=5&ns=botzr2uhj2w&s=1YC4q5rnZtSeb9VJZv0ZI7DikIK8Mz6g'
>   failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 =
>   1, reserved3 = 1

Edge:

> WebSocket Error: Network Error 12152, The server returned an invalid
>   or unrecognized response

Code:

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/tutorial/css/example.css"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);

      myApp.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",
        function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
          var ref = new Firebase("https://botzr2uhj2w.firebaseio-demo.com/");
          $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(ref);
        }
      ]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same problem occurs even when not using AngularFire as well.

Comment: Looks like there was an issue with our firebaseio-demo.com URLs. Things appear to be working now for me. If you are building a real app, you are better off using a real firebaseio.com URL since our -demo URLs do not have any SLA and can get wiped out / taken down at any time.

Comment: @jacobawenger This occurs with any firebase database, demo or not.

Comment: If you are experiencing network issues trying to connect to Firebase, please reach out to firebase-support@google.com with your Firebase database URL and some more information.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error code 12152 in IE11 when I had forgotten to enable Web Socket protocol on the server.

The server was Windows 2016 - I had to go to Programs -> Windows Features -> Web Server -> Application Development
The I enabled WebSocket Protocol.
Hit Next/OK and let it install.

Then the web clients were working.